# Tampermonkey script not firing on web app using websockets

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I use GM/TM scripts extensively and they work without fail except on one site: a Slack-style enterprise chat tool, Mattermost. The page loads, opens a websocket, then fetches the chat pane content and populates it.

As a test, I've used the most basic logic to just print a message to the console. The script applies to the entire domain and is shown as active, but no errors or logs are emitted.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         mattermost
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://*.cloud.mattermost.com/*
// @grant  none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log("test")
```

Approaches I have tried:

- Using various `@run-at` parameters
- Using waitForKeyElements, which usually works on sites loading in dynamic content
- Adding a timeout before firing
- Various invocations of `window.onload` and `unsafewindow.onload`

Commands issued directly to the console after the page has loaded in its entirety work, and the DOM can be manipulated at will. Is there some caveat I am missing here when it comes to websockets?

Comment: What's the *exact* URL you're running the script to?

Comment: The exact URL is as listed above: `https://*.cloud.mattermost.com/*`

The script appears as loaded in the TM icon when the page is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your "code" with a mattermost instance located on our company server. And the debug message showed up without a hassle.

As you said your script was marked as active the different match patterns shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).